# Child component is displayed under another child component

Tags: angular, selector, router-outlet

Child #1 Component:
selector: 'app-home'

child #2 component:
selector: 'app-plans'

child #1 html:

```
    <p>child 1 here</p>
```

child #2 html:

```
    <p>Child 2 here</p>
```

app.component.html:

```
<app-home></app-home>
```

app-routing.module.ts:

```
    const routes: Routes = [
    {path: 'plans', component: PlansComponent},
    {home: 'home', component: HomeComponent} 
    ]
```

in browser localhost:4200/plans displays:
child 1 here
child 2 here

if I change app.component.html to:

```
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

localhost:4200/plans displays:
child 2 here

What's wrong with using 'app-home' selector in app.component.html? why is it showing "child 1 here" in localhost:4200/plans? (i am expecting "child 2 here" only.)

shows results I expected, but I don't understand why  doesn't work as I expected.

Comment: Please provide the reproducible source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the router strategy you need to insert the [RouterOutlet](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet#routeroutlet) directive in your main component like you did `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`. The RouterOutlet directive is a placeholder that angular fills dynamically with the appropriate content based on the active route.

So if you have an active route like `localhost:4200/plans` and want to see only the component configured in the route definition `PlansComponent`, then you should just use `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your app component.

With `<app-home></app-home>` in your app component you are just statically rendering the `HomeComponent` and nothing to do with your routing implementation.